# C# MongoDB Count with Lookup or Match

Tags: c#, mongodb

So Suppose I have two Collections

```
User {
   string Id;
   string name;
}

Category {
   string Id;
   string userId;
   string name;
}

// For Look Up
UserJoined : User {
   public ICOllection<Category> Categories {get;set;}
}
```

I am trying to count using this kind of Query (SQL)

```
Expression<Func<User,bool>> query = p => p.User.Category.Name == "Apple";
```

Now the above works great in SQL using EF Core.

But I want to do something similar in Mongo DB Driver C#.

The Current situation fetches all the documents and then it Takes count, which is very very bad performance wise in the long run. I know there might be something.

I was looking at AddFields operator but I couldn't find a way to use it in my case.

Comment: You need MongoDB aggregation for this, which count in a single query.

Comment: Using Aggregation already for look Ups but the but don't know how to Count based on the condition of a Child/ Related Objects

Comment: What is the exact information you are trying to get here? Your EF LINQ query `p => p.User.Category.Name == "Apple";` looks like `User` has a single `Category`, but in your C# model, `User` has a collection of `Category` objects.

Comment: @MarkoPapic the classes are the Example for Mongo DB, I use those during LookUp for getting the Categories for each User.

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to get in MongoDB? Count of the users that contain a category with the name "Apple"?

Comment: @MarkoPapic exactly this

Answer (score 0):

This should get the count of users which contain a category with the name "Apple":

```cs
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
IMongoDatabase db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("your_db_name");
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> usersCollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users");

FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> matchFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch<BsonDocument>("categories", Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(c => c["name"], "Apple"));
AggregateCountResult result = usersCollection.Aggregate()
    .Match(matchFilter)
    .Count()
    .Single();

long count = result.Count;
```

Which is a C# representation of the following aggregation:

```js
db.users.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: {
            categories: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    name: "Apple"
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $count: "count"
    }]
)
```

Considering you have `users` collection with the following data:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "User 1",
    "categories": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "Orange"
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "Apple"
      },
      {
        "_id": 3,
        "name": "Peach"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "User 2",
    "categories": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "Orange"
      },
      {
        "_id": 3,
        "name": "Peach"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "User 3",
    "categories": [
      {
        "_id": 4,
        "name": "Banana"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "name": "User 4",
    "categories": [
      {
        "_id": 4,
        "name": "Banana"
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "Apple"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "name": "User 5",
    "categories": [
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "Apple"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Value of `count` variable will be 3.

Comment: his categories are in a seperate collection. not embedded in the user documents.

Answer (score 0):

if the goal is to get a count of users who has "Apple" as a category, you can simply do it like so:

```cs
var appleUserCount = await categoryCollection.CountDocumentsAsync(c=>c.Name == "Apple");
```

however, if there are duplicate categories (same userId and categoryName) then getting an accurate count gets a bit complicated and you'll have to do some grouping for getting a distinct user count.

test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApplication
{
    public class User : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category : Entity
    {
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            await DB.InitAsync("test");

            await DB.Index<Category>()
                    .Key(c => c.Name, KeyType.Ascending)
                    .CreateAsync();

            var user1 = new User { Name = "Fanboy" };
            var user2 = new User { Name = "Poolboy" };
            await new[] { user1, user2 }.SaveAsync();

            await new[] {
                new Category { Name = "Apple", UserID = user1.ID},
                new Category { Name = "Apple", UserID = user2.ID},
                new Category { Name = "Google", UserID = user1.ID}
            }.SaveAsync();

            var count = await DB.CountAsync<Category>(c => c.Name == "Apple");
        }
    }
}
```